# How does Google Image search with Image as parameter work?

Tags: image, search, comparison

I am interested in how google have done it's image search using an image. I am doing a project on image comparison and searching using images, and considering how impressive google image search using image seems to be, I am curious what they have done.

I also wonder how much they do actually image comparing and how much they use like keywords around images etc.